# PHP PDO Dependancy Injection

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

Thanks for reading and considering my question..

I am new to PDO and to OOP (the right way - I've been using objects more like functions for some time now), and I'm attempting to convert my current user login scripts to prevent session hijacking (whilst at the same time make getting data from the database easier)... anyway...

Additionally - I am doing this to learn, not because I need a login script. If I needed something like this I would use a framework that's already out there that has been proven.

I'm constructing this class for `UserSessions`, defined thus:

```
class UserSession {
public  $userSessionId;
public  $loggedInUserId;
public  $userIp;
public  $userFwdIp;
public  $httpUserAgent;
public  $authenticated;

private $hashedPassword;
private $suppliedUserName;
private $suppliedPassword;    

public function __construct ($pdoConn) {
    $this->setUserSessionId();
    $this->setUserIp();
    $this->setUserFwdIp();
    $this->setSessionExpire();
    $this->setHttpUserAgent();
    $this->setLoggedInUserId();
    $this->updateCurrentSession();
}
private function setLoggedInUserId() {
$query = 'select 1 from dual';
$this->loggedInUserId = $pdoConn->query($query)->fetch()[0];
}
// several other methods below that all function properly
}
```

I instantiate the class here:

```
$databaseConnect   = new $config['database_type']($config);
$pdoConn           = new PDO(   $databaseConnect->connectString
                            ,   $databaseConnect->getDataBaseUser()
                            ,   $databaseConnect->getDataBasePass()
                            ,   array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false
                            ,   pdo::ATTR_ERRMODE=>pdo::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
                            );
$httpReqUser       = new UserSession($pdoConn);
```

However, I get the below error:
 Call to a member function query() on null

So, this is telling me that the `$pdoConn` object is `null` (I think)... but I can't figure out why.

I have tried setting a new variable to the `$pdoConn` value that's passed in from outside of the constructor for local use like this:

```
$this->setPdoConn($pdoConn) // and within that method it's a simple setter...
```

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what exactly I should be doing here.

Basically - this `UserSession` class will need to update or insert a few fields into a table, nevertheless it will need access to PDO, but I don't want to have to call a 'new PDO' every time I want to use it in all of my classes. **How should I approach this?**

Comment: You might want to look into `dependency injection container` such as; http://php-di.org/ or http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: I am wondering whether setLoggedInUserId method is a real one

Comment: @tadman please see the third paragraph. ... @ your common sense, no that query just returns 1, but it only returns 1 if the connection is good.

Comment: @Jeff Although you say this is an academic exercise, you also hint that you're using this on other projects. While I'm all for learning, be very careful here testing this on unsuspecting users. [There's a lot of threats](http://owasp.org) you'll need to mitigate to get this to the level it needs to be. Do your best to be careful, and good luck with this.

Comment: Thanks Tadman. While i appreciate that feedback i assure you the sites my pathetic and insecure login scripts by no means contain sensitive data of any kind. This is a hobby for me and when it comes to true authentication and proper security i know to let experts do their job while i do mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor receives a `$pdoConn` parameter, but you aren't doing anything with it.

Create a class attribute, save `$pdoConn` in the constructor, and then use that to issue queries.

Like this:

```
class UserSession {
    private $pdoConn;
    // rest of your class attributes

    public function __construct ($pdoConn) {
        $this->pdoConn = $pdoConn;
        // rest of your constructor
    }

    private function setLoggedInUserId() {
        $this->loggedInUserId = $this->pdoConn->query(...)->fetch()[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Oddly enough I had tried that with a setter but it seems I must have done it wrong because this is working. Thank you!